# Tool sub-menus don't always appear

Tags: interface, versions

I'll be short. When i use some Blender tools which should make a sub-menu appear in the left window, it doesn't always happen. For example, according to a tutorial I was following, I should have gotten the sub-menu you see in the picture after using "spin", but it doesn't appear. Maybe it's something related to the fact that I'm using Blender 2.75 while the tutorial uses some 2.5x? How can I get that sub-menu to appear?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to click the little 'plus icon' to open the 'Redo Panel':

[image]

Comment: Wow, it was easier than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, you can press F6 on your keyboard after pressing 'spin' and the options will appear in a floating panel.